# Apexchart js how to change label inside the radian bar chart with java

Tags: vaadin, apexcharts

I'm using vaadin and java for my web application. I'm trying to show an average fuel consumption of a car. This is going to be of course in liters.

[image]

As can be see in the visual, the bottom part shows the percentage. Howerver, I want to show different value here than the actual 75.0. For example, I want radian bar to have yes 75% but in the label part, I want to write "7.5 liters" instead of 75%.

```
 ApexCharts averageFuelConsumption =
    ApexChartsBuilder.get()
        .withChart(
            ChartBuilder.get()
                .withType(Type.radialBar)
                .withToolbar(ToolbarBuilder.get().withShow(true).build())
                .build())
        .withPlotOptions(
            PlotOptionsBuilder.get()
                .withRadialBar(
                    RadialBarBuilder.get()
                        .withStartAngle(-135.0)
                        .withEndAngle(225.0)
                        .withHollow(
                            HollowBuilder.get()
                                .withMargin(0.0)
                                .withSize("70%")
                                .withBackground("#fff")
                                .withPosition(HollowPosition.front)
                                .withDropShadow(
                                    DropShadowBuilder.get()
                                        .withEnabled(false)
                                        .withTop(3.0)
                                        .withBlur(4.0)
                                        .withOpacity(0.24)
                                        .build())
                                .build())
                        .withDataLabels(
                            RadialBarDataLabelsBuilder.get()
                                .withShow(true)
                                .withName(
                                    NameBuilder.get()
                                        .withOffsetY(-10.0)
                                        .withShow(true)
                                        .withColor("#002366")
                                        .withFontSize("12px")
                                        .build())
                                .withValue(
                                    ValueBuilder.get()
                                        .withColor("#111")
                                        .withFontSize("36px")
                                        .withShow(true)
                                        .build())
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .build())
        .withFill(
            FillBuilder.get()
                .withType("gradient")
                .withGradient(
                    GradientBuilder.get()
                        .withShade("dark")
                        .withType("horizontal")
                        .withShadeIntensity(0.5)
                        .withGradientToColors("#ABE5A1")
                        .withInverseColors(true)
                        .withOpacityFrom(1.0)
                        .withOpacityTo(1.0)
                        .withStops(0.0, 100.0)
                        .build())
                .build())
        .withSeries(75.0)
        .withStroke(StrokeBuilder.get().withLineCap(LineCap.round).build())
        .withLabels("Ortalama Yakit Tüketimi")
        .build();
```

Comment: I think this should be possible with `withFormatter(new SuffixFormatter(""))` for `ValueBuilder`. But the add-on has an issue which prevents using the formatter: https://github.com/appreciated/apexcharts-flow/issues/92

Note also that the backing library supports only values between 0 and 100: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/449

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one on `DataLabels` Part

```
.withFormatter("function (val) { return val + \"%\"; }")
```